# How to retrieve data from firebase in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a todo-list app using React.
I'm able to save data into firebase database. However, I don't know how to retrieve those data and put them in JSX. I can print them in the console. Currently, I only output the todo lists by typing in the bar and press enter.

Here is my code. It's kinda messy.

```
   import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import firebase from 'firebase';

var config = {
    apiKey: "**********************",
    authDomain: "react-to-do-list-a8f6d.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://react-to-do-list-a8f6d.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "react-to-do-list-a8f6d",
    storageBucket: "react-to-do-list-a8f6d.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "673689778313"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const database = firebase.database();
const ref = database.ref('todos');




// const todos = []
class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            todo: '',
            todos: [],
            // database: 
        }
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this)
        this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this)
        this.check = this.check.bind(this)
    }
    handleInput(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo: e.target.value
        })
    }
    addTask(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            this.setState({
                todos: this.state.todos.concat(this.state.todo)
            })
            e.target.value = ''
            ref.push(this.state.todo)
        }
    }
    check(e) {
        if (e.target.style.textDecoration === "") {
            e.target.style.textDecoration = " line-through"
        } else {
            e.target.style.textDecoration = ""
        }
    }


    render() {

        ref.on('value', gotData, errData)

        function gotData(data) {
            let todos = data.val()
            // console.log(todos)
            let keys = Object.keys(todos)
            // console.log(keys)
            for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                let key = keys[i]
                let todo = todos[key]
                console.log(todo)
            }
        }

        function errData(err) {
            console.log('Error !')
            console.log(err)
        }

        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <h1>To Do List</h1>
                <input value={this.state.term} onKeyDown={this.addTask} onChange={this.handleInput} placeholder="  Add your tasks here"></input>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.todos.map(x => {
                        return (
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id={x} name={x} value={x} />
                                <label for={x}>{x}</label>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As firebase database is a real time DB, which means it gives you a reference to where data is and can trigger you whenever the data at the reference changes, this allows you to capture snapshots of data at the given reference.

You are almost correct to use `firebase.database().ref().on('value')` method to get the data at the reference.

You can further add a callback like the this:

```
firebase
      .database()
      .ref(
        firebase_basepath + `${tenantId}/${userId}/task/product/${referenceId}`
      )
      .on("value", snapshot => {
        console.log("FireB ",snapshot)
        if (snapshot && snapshot.exists()) {
           //Set values in state which can be extracted in jsx in render. 
        }})
```

Now with the state change the function will re render and the values can be set in the jsx.

Comment: You can also extract this out into componentDidMount, you only need to fire this once on render, keeping this in render will keep firing it everytime something in the UI forced a render.